# Storage requirement when using for AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ebs, amazon-ecs, docker-volume

I've setup AWS EC2 Container Service for our application and seems that AWS *forces* you to have a volume for the **linux OS** and another for **docker** (by default). Is there anyway around this?

Why must it be at least 22GB? I tried going down to 10 and 15 GB but the instance wouldn't even start...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the ECS optimized Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is set up, with a separate volume of that size. You can read more about it in the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html). You are completely free to create your own image that has Docker installed and runs the ECS Agent Docker container.

Take into account however that Amazon choose this setup for a reason. Docker images take up a lot of space and logically separating that space from the OS space makes sense. You can debate about 22 GB, but on the other hand; the cost of such a volume are very low on AWS.